# Yii - Disable default routing schema

Tags: routes, yii

Yii by default maps routes to: module/controller/action (like Zend)

How do I disable this and only use my custom rules?  I know how to ADD rules to main.php, but I'm trying to figure out how to disable this default routing schema so if none of my custom rules match, a 404 is returned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use only your defined routes you have to include `'useStrictParsing' => true` in your urlManager component definition in main.php

Comment: For Yii2, this would be `'enableStrictParsing' => true`